# Multi-user file upload in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating a web application in Spring that allows multiple users to upload files simultaneously that too by uploading the file in pieces,so that there are no memory issues, but my current code only lets 1 user upload a file at once. Until the 1st file is complete, the 2nd one does not start. How would i go about correcting this issue?

This is my Upload Form:

```
<body>
    <div th:if="${message}">
        <h2 th:text="${message}"></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
            <table>
                <tr><td>File to Upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
                <div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
                <output id="list"></output>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li th:each="file : ${files}">
                <a th:href="${file}" th:text="${file}" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my Controller

```
package hello;
import hello.storage.StorageFileNotFoundException;
import hello.storage.StorageService;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItemStream;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

private final StorageService storageService;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3447685998419256747L;
private static final String RESP_SUCCESS = "{\"jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\", \"result\" : \"success\", \"id\" : \"id\"}";
private static final String RESP_ERROR = "{\"jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\", \"error\" : {\"code\": 101, \"message\": \"Failed to open input stream.\"}, \"id\" : \"id\"}";
public static final String JSON = "application/json";
public static final int BUF_SIZE = 2 * 1024;
public static final String FileDir = "C:\\Users\\sshah\\Development\\Uploading Files\\upload-dir\\";

@Autowired
public FileUploadController(StorageService storageService) {
    this.storageService = storageService;
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {

    model.addAttribute("files", storageService
            .loadAll()
            .map(path ->
                    MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                            .build().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return "uploadForm";
}

@GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename) {

    Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFilename()+"\"")
            .body(file);
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  try {
      /*storageService.store(file);*/
      InputStream ip = file.getInputStream();
      saveUploadFile(ip, new File(FileDir + file.getOriginalFilename()));
  }


    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}

@ExceptionHandler(StorageFileNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleStorageFileNotFound(StorageFileNotFoundException exc) {
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}

private void saveUploadFile(InputStream input, File dst) throws IOException {
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        if (dst.exists()) {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dst, true),
                    BUF_SIZE);
        } else {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dst),
                    BUF_SIZE);
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != input) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (null != out) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-uploading-files</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And finally my Applications.properties file:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=15000MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=15000MB
```

I am only about 3 months old into Spring, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your html from `<input type="file" name="file" />` to `<input type="file" name="manyfiles" multiple/>` so your getting a form where you can select multiple files.

After this you just change the post method in your controller so that you get an array of MultipartFile. Than your can iterate over this array and  handle the files one by one.

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("manyfiles") MultipartFile[] files,
                           RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    for(MultipartFile file : files) {
        //Your upload code
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If you want an asynchonus upload pass the byted to the upload method an mark it async

```
@Async
public void process(byte[] bs){
    //do some long running processing of bs here
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                           RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    upload.process(IOUtils.toByteArray(file));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, but your solution lets me select multiple files. I wanted multiple users to upload files at the same time. Currently if User A is uploading a large file, User B's upload waits until the first one is completed. So basically I am looking at an asynchronous file upload.

Comment: Mark the upload async